# Summarize list of hours and topics into per-hour matrix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file like below:

```
9 0 topic1 hour=11
9 0 topic1 hour=12
9 0 topic1 hour=13
9 0 topic1 hour=14
9 0 topic1 hour=15
9 0 topic1 hour=16
9 0 topic1 hour=17
9 0 topic1 hour=18
9 0 topic1 hour=19
9 0 topic1 hour=20
9 0 topic1 hour=21
9 0 topic1 hour=22
9 0 topic1 hour=23
9 0 topic2 hour=00
9 0 topic2 hour=01
9 0 topic2 hour=02
9 0 topic2 hour=03
9 0 topic2 hour=04
9 0 topic2 hour=05
```

- First column is number of files in hour directory which is last column
- Second column is size in GB
- Third column is a parent hdfs direcory
- Last column is hourly directory inside the parent directory

I want the output to be in below format

```
            01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
topic1      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09  
topic2      09 09 09 09 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

That's hour-wise number of files per parent directory, in a tabular format. If size can be shown there, say comma-separated, that'd be great.

So far this is what I managed to create:

```
/bin/hdfs dfs -count <hdfs_path>/year=`date --date="1 days ago" +%Y`/month=`date --date="1 days ago" +%m`/day=`date --date="1 days ago" +%d`/*|awk '{print  $2, int($3/(1024*1024*1024)+0.5), $4}'|cut -d '/' -f1,5,9|sed 's/\// /g'| awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2, $3,"",$4}'|while read i
do
    for topic in topic1  topic2  topic3 
    do
        num_files=`echo $i|grep $topic|awk '{print  $1}'`
        size_gb=`echo $i|grep $topic|awk '{print  $2}'`
        hour=`echo $i|grep $topic|awk '{print  $4}'|cut -d "=" -f2`
    done        
done
```

I am trying to parse each line and then format a new line. Thought of checking if there is any other smart way there.

I am on Linux so Bash or Python can be used. Rest of the script I have managed to create so far is Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Awk anyway, use its capabilities.

```sh
awk '{ t[$3]; k[$3 ":" $4] += $1; s[$3 ":" $4] += $2; next }
  END {
    printf "%-11s", ""; for (h=0; h<=24; h++) printf "   %02i", h; printf "\n"
    for (d in t) {
      printf "%-11s", d;
      for (h=0; h<=24; h++)
      { hh = sprintf("%02i", h);
        printf " %02i,%i", k[d ":hour=" hh], s[d ":hour=" hh]
      }
      printf "\n"
    }
  }' topics
```

Sample output:

```
              00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
topic1      00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 00,0
topic2      09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 09,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0 00,0
```

The logic is very simple; we create an associative array `k` whose key is the topic and the hour, and a second array `t` of just the topics so we can loop over each topic later. For example, `k["topic2:hour=13"]` contains the value for `topic2` for hour `13`.  Similarly, `s["topic2:hour=13"]` contains the disk size for that topic and hour. Then at the end we just loop over the topics and the hours and pull out and print these values.

Comment: I have managed to fit this a little to my putty prompt, just formatting, but at my knowledge level, yours is a bit advance code. If possible, please help. Second field , should be hour wise. This is supposed to get me what happened yesterday, number of file in hour wise directory and its size, so size doesn't change. Its a kafka dump to hdfs, ran a day before, for different topics. THANKS A TON!!!

Comment: See updated answer now. I added a short explanation of the logic, too.

Comment: I wasn't sure if an hour could be repeated more than once for a topic, so that's why it adds these values rather than overwrites. You could use `=` instead of `+=` if we can be sure that every entry will be unique.

Comment: That just worked like a charm!! and thanks a ton for the explanation , I am gonna read more on awk arrays. Thanks again!!!

This question is answered by @tripleee

Comment: hour value wont be repeated